# Running "repairDatabase" with Monger?

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

Is it possible to execute the "repairDatabase" command with [Monger](http://clojuremongodb.info/)? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
(:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
          [monger.core :as mc]))

(deftest ^:focused repair-db-test
  (let [conn (mc/connect)
        db (mc/get-db conn "test-db")]
   (is (= {"ok" 1.0}
          (mc/command db {:repairDatabase 1})))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can just do:

```
(monger.core/command db {:repairDatabase 1})
```